# Back to search results

Tags: search, scripting

On the website I run we have a single search field where you can enter a name or profession. When you search you are served with a page full of results that come from 3 seperate sources.

Once you click on one field e.g. John Do, you will be taken to his page. On that page we have a back to search, but it goes to a blank screen.

I want to go back to the actual search results so the person doesn't have to do it all again, but I'm not sure where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: history.go（-1）works？

Comment: Here are a few ideas: 1. Open your result in a new browser window. 2. Include `sourceUrl` in the querystring and pass along the link to results page. 3. Just JS navigation function `window.history.back();`

Comment: I used <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Back to search results</a> which worked great! Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky situation.

There can be many solutions for this issue but I'll will name some of them.

1. Activate the cache of the pages (Quick trick, no suitable for websites that relies on users (*login)), you can go back and your form will be the same with the results without any issue.
2. Manage the load of the page of Jhon Do as a ajax load and #hashtag references, you don't reload the page but you just manage the states of the HTML. (Can be done with JS frameworks or React)
3. Depends on which platform are you working try to manage the variable of the search with this concept [post-redirect-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-redirect-get)

Hope that is helps!
Cheers.